# How can I unrelease my android app after releasing in playstore?

Tags: android

I released my app in playstore, but I want to change its current version to a beta version, and unrelease it.

How can I change the current released version of my app to be in testing phase (beta version)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpublish it, but it won't get removed from the devices of people who have already installed it. Unpublish the production application, Increment the app version code and publish a new beta version. Later you can either move the beta version to production again or increment the app version code and publish new version to the production.

Comment: Don't you mean 'You can unpublish it...'?

Comment: Yeah typo :D Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

To unpublish your app:
1- Go to your Play Console.
2- Select an app.
3- Select Store presence > Pricing & distribution.
4- In the "App Availability" section, select Unpublish.
Hope this is help

Comment: Setup -> Advanced setting -> App Availability -> Unpublished